# The “privileges” page doesn't render well in Safari

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

The page that displays [which privileges the logged-in user has](https://english.stackexchange.com/privileges) and how close they are to achieving the rest appears to ahve a display error:

That's Safari 5.1.4 on Mac OS 10.7.3. See the badly-rendered table at right:

[image]

Comment: It's the same in Google Chrome under WinXP.

Comment: I was going to report this too, but I found out it was already reported. To me, it happens with Safari 5.1.5 on Mac OS X 10.7.3, and Google Chrome 17.0.963.83 running on the same OS.

Comment: Ditto for all of Firefox 11, Chrome 17, and Safari 5.1 on Mac OS X 10.7. Also on Safari for iOS.

Comment: @Jin please fix!

Comment: Same in Chrome 19 and IE 8 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the following style-rule change in the CSS file **http://cdn.sstatic.net/english/all.css** would fix this:

```
body.privileges-page #sidebar {
    width: 220px; /* was 240px */
}
```